# Drop MongoDB database before running Mocha test

Tags: mongodb, testing, mongoose, mocha.js, should.js

If I try to drop the database using `after` (at the end of my tests) it works.

If I try the following:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db-test')

describe('Database', function() {

    before(function (done) {
        db.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(){
            done()
        })
    })

    ...
```

it does not drop the DB. what is going on? I would prefer dropping the db before starting testing -- so that after testing I can explore the db.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solved by connect in another define.. not sure if ideal.

```
describe('Init', function() {

    before(function (done) {   
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db-test', function(){
            mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(){
                done()
            })    
        })
    })

    describe('Database', function() {
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My guess is that the connections isn't available yet at the time of starting your tests.

Comment: You can do it with [mongo-interlude](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-interlude) by simply pass your mongoose adapter to `cleanDb` function. It also doesnt destroy models, but clear their entites.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented it a bit different.

1. I removed all documents in the "before" hook - found it a lot faster than dropDatabase().
2. I used Promise.all() to make sure all documents were removed before exiting the hook.

   ```
   beforeEach(function (done) {

       function clearDB() {
           var promises = [
               Model1.remove().exec(),
               Model2.remove().exec(),
               Model3.remove().exec()
           ];

           Promise.all(promises)
               .then(function () {
                   done();
               })
       }

       if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
           mongoose.connect(config.dbUrl, function (err) {
               if (err) {
                   throw err;
               }
               return clearDB();
           });
       } else {
           return clearDB();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: dropping database will lose all the indexes.  this is a better way.